# Dynamic Linq Group by Join and Count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, dynamic-linq

Good day.
Need some help with Dynamic Linq Query.
I have the following SQL.

```
Select t.CustomerKey , Count(1)
    from dbo.Products p
    inner join dbo.Transactions t on t.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
    Where p.CategoryLevel3 = 'xxx'
    group by t.CustomerKey
    having count(1) > 2
```

I am using Entity Framework. The linq query I have that gives me the same result is.

```
var result2 = entities.Products.Join(entities.Transactions, p => p.ProductKey, t => t.ProductKey, (p, t) => new { p, t })
                               .Where(z => z.p.CategoryLevel3 == "xxx")
                               .GroupBy(c => new { c.t.CustomerKey })
                               .Select(x => new { x.Key.CustomerKey, count = x.Count() })
                               .Where(y => y.count > 2);
```

So far I have the following Dynamic Linq

```
var result2 = entities.Products.Join(entities.Transactions, p => p.ProductKey, t => t.ProductKey, (p, t) => new { p, t })
                               .Where("z => z.p." + filterCondition)
                               .GroupBy("c => new { c.t." + groupByField + "}")
                               .Select("x => new (x.Key as CustomerKey, x." + selectfunction + "() as count)")
                               .Where("y => y.count" + groupByFilterComparisonOperator + groupByFilterInputValue);
```

I get a Syntax Error on the Select Line.

> filterCondition = "CategoryLevel3 == "xxx""

> groupByField ="CustomerKey"

> selectfunction ="Count"

> groupByFilterComparisonOperator =">"

> groupByFilterInputValue = "2"

Comment: What is the syntax error you get?

Comment: System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'Syntax error'

Comment: @TheoKoekemoer Have you tried to debug it incrementally? Starting with a single query with dynamic Where condition then adding join, etc...

Comment: Yes the problem is in the .Select Statement

Comment: Your `Select` contain syntax errors. `.Select("x => new (x.Key as CustomerKey, x." + selectfunction + "() as count)")` should be `.Select("x => new { CustomerKey = x.Key, Count = x." + selectfunction + "() }")`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
var result2 = entities.Products.Join(entities.Transactions, p => p.ProductKey, t => t.ProductKey, (p, t) => new { p, t })
                               .Where("z => z.p." + filterCondition)
                               .GroupBy("c => new { c.t." + groupByField + "}")
                               .Select("new (Key , " + selectfunction + "() as count)")
                               .Where("count" + groupByFilterComparisonOperator + groupByFilterInputValue);
```